# Multiple conditional Statment error, What's the problem

Tags: php, conditional-statements

I get this error...

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected
>   '{', expecting '(' in
>   /home/content/s/k/y/skyview09/html/clients/Cheryl/admin/admin.php
>   on line 122

when trying to run a page with multiple conditional statements (if, elseif, else).

The php that I'm tying to run is:

```
<?php

            if(isset($_GET['message'])){
                echo "<p><font color='#fff'>Your update was successful!</font></p>";
            }

            require("includes/connection.php");
            $article = (isset($_GET['article'])) ? $_GET['article'] : "1";
            $page = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? $_GET['page'] : "1";
            $nav = (isset($_GET['nav'])) ? $_GET['nav'] : "none";

            if($nav != "none"){

                $sql = "SELECT id, name, url, title content FROM nav WHERE id='$nav'";
                $result = $conn->query($sql) or die('Something is wrong on the test.php...Check it OUT! admin page, navigation');
                if($result){
                    $row = $result->fetch_object();
                    echo '<form method="post" action="update.php">';
                    echo '<input type="hidden" name="id" value="' . $row->id . '" />';
                    echo 'Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="' . $row->name . '" /><br>';
                    echo 'Url: <input type="text" name="url" value="' . $row->url . '" /><br>';
                    echo 'Title: <input type="text" name="title" value="' . $row->title . '" /><br>';
                    echo '<input type="submit" name="editLinks" value="Update Content" />';
                    echo '</form>';
                }

            } elseif {

            $sql = "SELECT id, content FROM articles WHERE id='$article'";
            $result = $conn->query($sql) or die('Something is wrong on the test.php...Check it OUT! admin page, articles');
                if($result){
                    $row = $result->fetch_object();
                    echo '<form method="post" action="update.php">';
                    echo '<input type="hidden" name="id" value="' . $row->id . '"';
                    echo '<textarea name="content" cols="50" rows="15">';
                    echo $row->content;
                    echo '</textarea>';
                    echo '<input type="submit" name="editContent" value="Update Content" />';
                    echo '</form>';
                }
            }

            else {

            $sql = "SELECT id, content FROM pages WHERE id='$page'";
            $result = $conn->query($sql) or die('Something is wrong on the test.php...Check it OUT! admin page, pages');
                if($result){
                    $row = $result->fetch_object();
                    echo '<form method="post" action="update.php">';
                    echo '<input type="hidden" name="id" value="' . $row->id . '"';
                    echo '<textarea name="content" cols="50" rows="15">';
                    echo $row->content;
                    echo '</textarea>';
                    echo '<input type="submit" name="editContent" value="Update Content" />';
                    echo '</form>';
                }
            }
            ?>
```

I would like the last "else" statement to be in the place of the "elseif" statement. And the elseif to be the last one. I tried some solutions, but nothing really worked. I don't know what the problem is.

I thought I would find the solution already to my problem in the SO questions, but not they're not exactly for my problem. I would appreciate the help.

Comment: Your code contains SQL-Injection bugs!

Comment: @ Bernd: It does? I didn't know. Where and how do I fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies in your `elseif` statement, you need to provide a condition to the `elseif`.

```
} elseif {
```

Should be

```
} elseif(some-condition) {
```

**All I did was read the error.**

Answer (score 0):

You are missing condition in elseif.

Answer (score 0):

`elseif` should contain a condition. Example:

```
if (condition1) {
   //
} elseif(condition2) {
   //
}
```